# How to get file name before upload using CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to upload files to my server with CodeIgniter, and I need to change the file name dynamically with some random numbers.

But before changing the name I also need the original name to store it in the database. How can I do that?

Comment: It would be good if you provide a sample of your code.

Comment: Why do you want the 2?

Comment: Why are you editing your question and rewriting it completely? Now your question is completely different from origin and answer is not related to new question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add these arrays to new one:

```
$newArray = [
   $oldArray[4],
   $oldArray[5],
   $oldArray[7],
   $oldArray[8],
   $oldArray[10],
   $oldArray[11],
];
```

**EDIT**
for dynamic, use something like that (not tested):

```
var newArray = [];
var oldArray = [/* ... */];

function addElement(eId){
    newArray.push(oldArray[eId]);
}

$.each(SomeRandomArrayIndexes, function(k, eId){
    addElement(eId);
});
```

Comment: I can't use static indexes,it comes dynamically!

Comment: ok thanks, one more question: I want to upload multiple file using codeigniter, codeigniter allows total 2mb files to be uploaded at once, if the total size of my selected files exceeds 2mb, then i cant upload the files, any suggestions plz ????

Comment: @user3606947 i don't really know codeigniter limitation. But this limitation comes from php.ini. So if you can access php.ini, than you can change upload_max_filesize and post_max_size to increase limit. If you can't modify php.ini, display limitations message, or use ajax file upload to upload one file at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which browsers you support you can use some of the functional extensions to the array prototype. Namely `filter` and `every`.

```
var arr = [[1,null,null],[1,null,null],[1,5,2],[null,null,null],[null,1,null],[1,2,3]];

var filtered = arr.filter(function(x){
  return x.every(function(value){
    return value != undefined;
  });
});

console.log(filtered);
```